# Como listar arquivos no PHP com um nome especifico?

Tags: php

Bom Dia
eu possou o código abaixo.

```
 <?php
 $diretorio = "../../arquivos/nest"; 
 $ponteiro  = opendir($diretorio);
 while ($nome_itens = readdir($ponteiro)) {
$itens[] = $nome_itens;
}
sort($itens);
foreach ($itens as $listar) {
if ($listar!="." && $listar!=".."){ 
            if (is_dir($listar)) { 
                    $pastas[]=$listar; 
            } else{ 
                    $arquivos[]=$listar;
            }
   }
}
if ($pastas != "" ) { 
foreach($pastas as $listar){
print "<img src='pasta.png'> <a href='$diretorio/$listar'download>$listar</a><br>";} 
   }
if ($arquivos != "") {
foreach($arquivos as $listar){
print "<a href='$diretorio/$listar' download>$listar</a><br>";}
}
?>
```

O Código funciona corretamente, minha duvida é. Quero criar uma variável que vai ter um texto especifico e que vai servir de filtro para mostrar os arquivos que tem no diretório com a variável em questão.

Exemplo: Na variável conter a informação "Carros", quando gerar a listagem só apareça os arquivos no diretórios que tiverem no nome do arquivos "Carros".

Comment: Esse código aí eu acho que é do site PHP Brasil. Tá meio desatualizadinho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu acho que você fez de um jeito mais complicado possível.

Era mais simples utilizar a função `glob` contendo a expressão desejada:

```
 $expr = '/caminho/para/pasta/Carros*.txt';

 foreach (glob($expr) as $path) {
       echo $path;
 }
```

Outra forma é utilizando a função `strpos` pra saber se tem a parte desejada no nome do arquivo.

No caso, vou usar uma forma mais atual para listar diretórios, que é através do `FileSystemIterator`

```
$arquivos = array();
$termo = 'Carros';
$iterator = new FileSystemIterator('diretório/desejado/aqui');
foreach ($iterator as $file) {

      $filename = $file->getRealpath();

      if (strpos($filename, $termo) !== false) {
         $arquivos[] = $filename;
      }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, a primeira funcionou certinho, mas mostra todo caminho do diretório, A forma mais atual sua está aparecendo erro, `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['` na linha da variavel $arquivos.

Comment: @Junior isso é porque a tua versão php é antiga, faz `$arquivos = array();`

Comment: Obrigado, @Miguel, é isso mesmo. Eu até alterei a resposta pra ele entender melhor

Comment: @WallaceMaxters de nada, eu vi que só podia ser isso. Bom dia

Comment: a minha versão do PHP 5.2